# Disable "The original suggestion was not helpful" option if the edit suggestion wasn't modified (significantly)

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, suggested-edits

This evening, I've had reviewers edit my "suggested edit" with minor changes, twice, with the reviewers selecting the "The original suggestion was not helpful" option.
(So, they use most of my edit, and then take credit) [I've asked a question about this on stack exchange, already.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156995/policy-on-incomplete-edit-suggestions)

I would like to suggest a feature to disable this "The original suggestion was not helpful", when the suggestion wasn't significantly edited, just like you can't suggest a edit when the reason's less than 10 letters, you shouldn't be able to take credit for a edit you're reviewing, unless you've significantly changed the suggested edit, yourself.

It's not that I'm frustrated by a possible reduced rep gain or anything, it's just impolite to take credit for another person's work.

Comment: I agree with the sentiment - it's definitely inconsistent to say it was unhelpful if the improvement edit was small compared to the original edit. This ratio clearly isn't hard to calculate.

Comment: It's worth noting that the person who rejected one of the edits specifically said it was a mistake, and he shouldn't have done it.  Do you have any indications that this is a serious problem happening fairly often?  One single problematic example doesn't seem like reason to start making significant changes to the system.

Comment: The "workaround" for the reviewer would be to flat out reject the edit without improving it (which was the only option until last year). That's not going to make the site better.

Comment: @Servy: Aside from it happening 2 times within one hour? And the user that said it was a mistake could've been notified of it, before applying the edit. Bo: True, but wouldn't that show in the editer's profile / logs? If someone were to abuse it like that, it shouldn't be too hard to detect.

Comment: That it happened two times within an hour still isn't compelling evidence in my eyes.  I spend a lot of time reviewing content, due to the problems with the system that means a lot of exposure to how everyone else is using that system.  I find this issue to be quite rare in my experiences.  I consider this to be an exceptional circumstance given what I've seen so far.  I'm not sure what you're saying the reviewer could've been notified of.  From what I can tell he knows well enough what should and shouldn't be marked as helpful, he just made a mistake this once; we're human, that happens.

Comment: One of them was a mistake, the other was a different person.
This isn't the first time it's happened to me.
He could've been notified of the fact that he was "claiming" a edit he barely modified. No mistakes is better than makin a mistake "this once". If one user makes the mistake, more will, especially on a site this size.

Comment: @Cerbrus - I guess you are arguing with the wrong set of people here. We edit posts all the time, without getting any points at all. If someone were to lose 2 or 4 rep because of a mistake, that's just not  a big deal. We have much bigger problems with reviewers accepting every suggested edit they see, just so they can get a new badge.